# Date snapshot table transformation in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, dimensional-modeling

Data transformation issue on Postgres. I have a process where submission is made, and some stages/events take place to process the submission. A row is created per submission. When an stage is complete, a timestamp populates the column for that stage.

The raw data is in the format

```
submission_id   stage1.time    stage2.time   stage3.time
XYZ             2016/01/01     2016/01/04    2016/01/05
```

I want to make a "snapshot" table for this (perhaps theres a better name for this?) which looks as follows, for the above example

```
snapshot_date  submission_id  stage_number  days_in_stage
2016/01/01     XYZ            1             0
2016/01/02     XYZ            1             1
2016/01/03     XYZ            1             2
2016/01/04     XYZ            2             0
2016/01/05     XYZ            3             0
```

So basically, on a given date in the past, what submissions are in what stages and how long had they been in those stages.

So far I've managed to generate a date table using

```
 SELECT ts::date
 FROM  (
         SELECT min(stage1.time) as first_date
              , max(stage1.time) as last_date
         FROM   schema.submissions
         ) h
        , generate_series(h.first_date, h.last_date, interval '1 day') g(ts)
```

but I'm stuck on where I should be joining next, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Right now there are about 4 stages but this number might change

Comment: I think it really doesn't matter. thanks and sorry.

Comment: min(stage1.time) and max(stage1.time) will always return 2016/01/01, are you getting the correct first_date and last_date?